# C++98 : Thread stopped

Tags: c++

I am making a hangman game and have encountered the problem.

```
Thread 1 stopped C:\Users........... Fault Access Violation at 0x4041e6: write of address 0x1a0000
```

I get the above error when I run my program , can you please help and tell me wat is the problem with the code

In the code , a is an object of a `player` class which has a function `retdifficulty()` which returns a string containing the difficulty chosen by the player.easy , medium and hard are text files that contain 20 lines each

```
int gen()
{
    randomize();
   int j = random(10);
   int a[]={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18};
   return a[j];
}
/***********************************************
Function to get a word from file
***********************************************/
char *getword()
{
   int j = gen();
   string word;
   string wordlist[20];
   if (strcmpi(a.retdifficulty(),"easy")==0)
   {
      int x = 0;
      ifstream fin("easy.txt");
      while (fin>>word)
      {
         strcpy(wordlist[x],word);
         x++;
      }
      return wordlist[j];
   }
   if (strcmpi(a.retdifficulty(),"medium")==0)
   {
      int x = 0;
      ifstream fin2("medium.txt");
      while (fin2>>word)
      {
        strcpy(wordlist[x],word);
         x++;
      }
      return wordlist[j];
   }
   if (strcmpi(a.retdifficulty(),"hard")==0)
   {
      int x = 0;
      ifstream fin3("hard.txt");
      while (fin3>>word)
      {
         strcpy(wordlist[x],word);
         x++;
      }
      return wordlist[j];
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried the debugger

Comment: Run debugger, say at which line it crashes.

Comment: @EdHeal the statement x++(in the medium block) gets flagged

Comment: @Randl x++ (in the medium block)

Comment: BTW you cannot return `std::string` as `char *`. And it bad practice to use both simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code (remember to add `#include<vector>`)

```
int gen()
{
    randomize();
    return random(10) * 2;
}
/***********************************************
Function to get a word from file
***********************************************/
string getword()  {
   int j = gen();
   string word, fname = "easy.txt";
   vector<string> wordlist;
   ifstream fin; 

   if (strcmpi(a.retdifficulty(),"medium")==0)
      fname = "medium.txt";
   else if (strcmpi(a.retdifficulty(),"hard")==0)
      fname = "hard.txt";

   fin.open(fname);
   while (fin>>word)
      wordlist.push_back(word);

   return wordlist[j];
}
```

Comment: @neema525 have you added `#include <vector>`?

Comment: And `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @neema525 I don't know, I use vector like 10 times every day, on different machines. It should work. I can't say what the problem without source code.

Comment: Randle, you use vector 10 times a day, but likely not with a compiler from 1997. @neema525 Odds are pretty good that you'll have to do something goofy or import a third-party library to get std containers to work. I Seriously recommend a compiler upgrade.

Comment: @user4581301 c++98 supports vectors. And I use them on machines with no support of newer standards too.

Comment: C++98... Meditate on what that means to a compiler last updated in 1997.

Comment: @user4581301 I just though that neema525 knows better what he needs, so he wrote C++98 in header

Answer (score 0):

The likely point of death in this code snippet is:

```
  while (fin>>word)
  {
     strcpy(wordlist[x],word);
     x++;
  }
```

Looks groovy except for two things:

```
string word;
string wordlist[20];
```

and

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Feeding `string` into a function expecting `char *` should be generating a compiler warning even in 1997.

My first inclination is to use std::string's assignment operator to do the copy

```
  while (fin>>word)
  {
     wordlist[x] = word;
     x++;
  }
```

It should work, but I can't guarantee this in a pre-standardization compiler.

The other usual notes about the brittleness of arrays hold, but the standard, "use std::vector." suggestion is problematic because there was no std::vector at the time. There was no standard.

So the first suggestion is upgrade the compiler and start using C++, not it's forefather.

If this is an assignment with toolchain forced upon the OP by an instructor who has managed to miss the last 20 years, shame on the institute for allowing the fool to hinder, if not outright damage, the learning of their students. If you are going to teach a language, teach the language.

Unless this is for a History of Programming course.